# There exists a 10×10 real symmetric matrix A , all of whose entries are nonnegative and all of whose diagonal entries are positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**MCQ**: There exists a $10 \times 10$ real symmetric matrix $A$, all of whose entries are nonnegative and all of whose diagonal entries are positive, such that $A^{10}$ has

a. exactly $68$ positive entries.

b. exactly $67$ positive entries.

c. exactly $69$ positive entries.

d. exactly $70$ positive entries.

**My Attempt**: If $A$ has such property then $A$ has even number of positive entries. Since $A^{10}$ has also same property like $A$, so, $A^{10}$ has even number of positive entries. So $b,c$ is incorrect statement. But what about option $a,d$. Give some hints.

Comment: Hint: What can you say about $A^{10}$? In particular, is there any unique characterization that might not apply to $A$?

Comment: This was asked two months ago in a [now deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4616067).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** What can you say about the positive entries of $A^{10}$?
In particular, is there any unique characterization that might not apply to $A$, or even $A^8$?

> With a suitable permutation of rows and columns, the positive entries of $A^{10}$ occur in block matrices along the diagonal.
>  Every entry in the block must be positive.
>  The rest of the entries are 0.

How can we prove the above characterization?

> Taking the graph theoretic interpretation of matrices, we're asking which vertices are connected to each other (since we're given self loops at each vertex) in at most 10 steps.
>
>  Note that since there are 10 vertices, any 2 connected vertices are connected in at most 9 steps. Thus these are exactly the subsets of connected vertices. Clearly between any 2 connected vertices, there is at least a path of length 10 between them, so the corresponding entry is positive.
>
>  In fact, this characterization also applies to $A^9$, but not necessarily to $A^8$.

**Corollary:** $a$ is possible. How? Can you construct such a matrix?
$d$ is not possible. Why not?

> $68 = 8^2 + 2^2$.

Comment: is there any linear algebraic argument of your claim? .  Thank you very much. Very nice.

Comment: @SJoseph Nothing that immediately comes to mind which isn't a re-statement of the graph theoretic interpretation. IE We could say that the $i,j$ entry of $A^2$ is positive if and only if there is some $k$ where $ A_{i, k}$ and $A_{k, j}$ are both positive, so on and so forth.

Comment: [+1] Once more, the fructful graph interpretation of matrices (that can be considered at once as (0-1) matrices). A little precision in the first paragraph : one should add "The positive entries of $A^{10}$
 occur in block matrices along the diagonal **up to a suitable permutation of lines and columns**...

Comment: can you please explain this question a bit more? I could not get it.

Comment: @MansiTyagi Explain what you tried, and what you do not understand.